# Triggering of aws lambda when a new model version gets registered in aws sagemaker

Tags: lambda, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I need to trigger aws lambda whenever a new model version is getting registered in aws Sagemaker model registry, which in turn will trigger sagemaker pipeline from lambda. Can anyone help how to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this:

1. You can utilize boto3 to list the model versions within your model package group to track whenever a new model is added. When a new model is added you can then have some client code to trigger a Lambda function (EventBridge, etc).

```
sm_client.list_model_packages(ModelPackageGroupName=model_package_group_name)
```

2. You can have this as part of the Pipelines itself. Have a register model step and then a Lambda step within Pipelines to execute whatever is necessary for you. A Lambda step within SageMaker Pipelines is essentially a Lambda function that you can plug in.